# Expected output of step in a Scikit learn feature union step

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a Scikit learn pipeline which includes a feature union as so

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('feats', FeatureUnion([
        #
        ('Vec', Doc2vec()),
        ('Counter', I_counter()),
    ])),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())  # classifier
])
```

Each of the two processes in the feature union are classes I've written myself. The first of these is a self written vectorizer based on the Gensim Doc2Vec model. Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/FMCumhaill/971a6390c76369202fb7945dd937ee90)

If I understand the feature union documentation correctly, it runs each step in parallel and concatenates the output vectors into a single vector passed to the next step (The CLF pipeline in this case).

I wrote each class to return a single numpy array, however the above code is triggering an error.

```
TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform. 'Pipeline(memory=None, steps=[('vec', Doc2vec())])' (type <class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>) doesn't
```

If I understand the error correctly (?), it's stating that the Doc2vec class is not outputting a suitable feature?

The Doc2vec class outputs a single numpy array, containing a 100 vector array for each inputted text sequence. I naively assumed it would simply concatenate this to the I_counter output and all work happyly.

Might someone be able to highlight where my logic is wrong?

--
**EDIT, more code**

```
class Doc2vec(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self


def vec(data):
    print('starting')
    SentimentDocument = namedtuple('SentimentDocument', 'words tags split sentiment')

    alldocs = []

    for line_no, line in data.iterrows():
        #tokens = gensim.utils.to_unicode(line).split()
        words = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line['post'])
        tags = [line_no] # 'tags = [tokens[0]]' would also work at extra memory cost
        split = ['train', 'test'][line_no//1200]  # 25k train, 25k test, 25k extra
        if gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line['type']) == ['depression']:
                        sentiment = (1.0)
        else:
                sentiment = (0.0)
        alldocs.append(SentimentDocument(words, tags, split, sentiment))



    train_docs = [doc for doc in alldocs if doc.split == 'train']
    test_docs = [doc for doc in alldocs if doc.split == 'test']

    #print('%d docs: %d train-sentiment, %d test-sentiment' % (len(alldocs), len(train_docs), len(test_docs)))
    from random import shuffle
    doc_list = alldocs[:]  
    shuffle(doc_list)
    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    assert gensim.models.doc2vec.FAST_VERSION > -1, "This will be painfully slow otherwise"

    simple_models = [

        # PV-DM w/ default averaging; a higher starting alpha may improve CBOW/PV-DM modes
        Doc2Vec(dm=1, vector_size=100, window=10, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample=0, 
                epochs=20, workers=cores, alpha=0.05, comment='alpha=0.05')
    ]

    for model in simple_models:
        model.build_vocab(train_docs)
        #print("%s vocabulary scanned & state initialized" % model)

    models_by_name = OrderedDict((str(model), model) for model in simple_models)
    model.train(train_docs, total_examples=len(train_docs), epochs=model.epochs)
    train_targets, train_regressors = zip(*[(doc.words, doc.sentiment) for doc in train_docs])
    import numpy as np
    X = []
    for i in range(len(train_targets)):
        X.append(model.infer_vector(train_targets[i]))
    train_x = np.asarray(X)
    print(type(train_x))
    return(train_x)


class I_counter(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self
​

​
  def transform(self, data):
    def i_count(name):
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(name)
        count = tokens.count("I")
        count2 = tokens.count("i")
        return(count+count2)
    vecfunc = np.vectorize(i_count)
    data =  np.transpose(np.matrix(data['post']))
    result = vecfunc(data)
    return result
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete code for doc2vec and I_counter ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif done!

Comment: your class Doc2vec()  doesn't define a transform method.  you have created on fit method only. transform method is missing.

Comment: Ah ok! Should it just return the data or do something else?